# Alphabetically sort MYSQL result by letter ignoring the prefix 'The '

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I can sort the whole thing A-Z and it works fine, but if i try and sort by just 1 letter, it doesnt work..

For instance:

```
"SELECT *,TRIM(LEADING 'the ' FROM LOWER(title)) AS title_x FROM table ORDER BY title_x ASC"
```

this works fine and sorts/fetches the results A-Z disregarding the 'The '..
But:

```
"SELECT *,TRIM(LEADING 'the ' FROM LOWER(title)) AS title_x FROM table WHERE title_x LIKE 'A%' ORDER BY title_x ASC"
```

doesnt work, it just says "Unknown column 'title_x' in 'where clause'"

Can anyone help me correct this? Thanks.

**UPDATE**

For anyone else having this problem, changing the WHERE for HAVING makes this work perfectly.

Comment: you can't use a column in a WHERE clause (as an alias) if the column itself doesn't exist.

Comment: So how can i achieve this then?

Comment: `WHERE title LIKE` or whatever real column exists

Comment: But that wont ignore 'The ' will it?

Comment: you've been given an answer, try that

Answer (score -2):

i think its not possible to use alias in where clause. You can use sub-query or nested query to solve this issue.

Comment: That was established in comments. Did you have any code to back this up with? Your question is of low-quality right now and is more of a comment really.